# How to merge two videos that are stored in Azure Blob?

Tags: azure, video, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, video-processing

```
dest_blob_name = "testvideo17.mp4"

blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(dest_blob_name)

my_content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='video/mp4')
blob_client.create_append_blob(my_content_settings)
blob_client.append_block_from_url(sas_url_video1)
blob_client.append_block_from_url(sas_url_video2)
```

I am trying to combine two blobs that both have a video into one single blob. While the blob is getting appended and code is running fine, the final video does not seem to be able to play both parts. Only one video plays. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Considering video files are binary files with metadata embedded into it, I don't think you will be able to combine the two video files like the way you're doing. It would have been a different story if the files were text files.

What you would need to do is download both videos on client side and then concatenate them using something like [`FFmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/). Then you would need to upload the resulting file back in your storage account.

A quick search on `concatenating videos using ffmpeg` lead me to this link: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate.